# How to use the flutter downgrade command to switch to an older version of Flutter SDK?

Tags: flutter

I got the following error when trying to switch to an older version (1.17.4) from my current version (Flutter 1.20.1 • channel stable).

```
> flutter downgrade
There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable".
Channel "beta" was previously on: 1.17.0-dev.3.1
```

`flutter downgrade` is the recommended way for switching versions instead of the deprecated `flutter version` command. However, there's no documentation I may refer to how it is used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another approach to downgrading is to change to the `flutter-sdk` directory and using `git` you can checkout a particular tag.

List the available tags with:

```
git tag
```

Then switch to a particular one with (e.g.):

```
git checkout 1.24.0-10.2.pre
```

(as I had to do today).

Note that this will switch which channel you are on and lock you at that version until you switch back with something like `flutter channel dev` once you believe the issue you faced is resolved.

Answer (score 10):

in my case , I switched `flutter channel master` then `flutter downgrade v1.22.6` it work

or by using git
`git checkout 1.24.0-10.2.pre`(any version name)

Answer (score 8):

Check your flutter channel:

```
flutter channel
```

Show like this:

```
Flutter channels:
   master
   dev
   beta
 * stable
```

Change to master:

```
flutter channel master
```

Run command:

```
flutter downgrade v1.22.6
```

Answer (score 6):

`flutter downgrade` only works if you have a previous version of flutter installed from the same channel. It seems like you don't, so please use `flutter version v1.17.4`.

Find a list of flutter versions here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases

Comment: It's `flutter downgrade`  not `flutter-downgrade` now

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep both versions just download a zip of old version and put in the same folder where is a new version and change its name   or you can change flutter path